# SQL query: how to create subtotal rows when there is no aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a function in SQL that can display subtotal rows. I have a table like this:

```
Date    INVNUNBER     CUSTOMER     ITEM     QTY     SALES
20190630 IN3343       joe's comp   23225    2.0     3000
20190630 IN3343       joe's comp   23214    1.0     400
20190630 IN3353       matt's comp. 12222     3.0     6000
20190630 IN3353       matt's comp. 32222     3.0     3000
```

I tried ROLLUP, but seems like ROLLUP requires an aggregate function where I have to SUM up one of the fields, and all other fields need to be in the `Group By` clause, but I don't really need anything grouped:

I tried:

```
SELECT DATE, INVNUMBER, CUSTOMER, ITEM, QUANTITY, SALES
FROM OESHDT
WHERE DATE = '20190630'
GROUP BY DATE, INVNUMBER, CUSTOMER WITH ROLLUP
```

then I get:

> Column 'OESHDT.ITEM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I just want to get the subtotals for each invoice number like this:

```
Date    INVNUNBER     CUSTOMER     ITEM     QTY     SALES
20190630 IN3343       joe's comp   23225    2.0     3000
20190630 IN3343       joe's comp   23214    1.0     400
                                           3.0     3400
20190630 IN3353       matt's comp. 12222     3.0     6000
20190630 IN3353       matt's comp. 32222     3.0     3000 
                                             6.0    9000
```

Since I'm not summing up anything and I only want subtotals for each, can SQL do this?

Comment: What is really your question here? it is clear you need SUM and GROUP BY ROLLUP here as it makes the most sense in this case.

Comment: then how to get it to preserver every line on the original table, but add a subtotal in between? seems like i have to group every column, with rollup, it will create a subtotal between every line, even between items on the same invoice..which is not what i need

Comment: pretty sure that  `GROUP BY ROLLUP` places the subtotal in the way as you want in the expected results, unless i miss something obvious here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is `Grouping Sets`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Date] varchar(50),[INVNUNBER] varchar(50),[CUSTOMER] varchar(50),[ITEM] varchar(50),[QTY] int,[SALES] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (20190630,'IN3343','joe''s comp',23225,2.0,3000)
,(20190630,'IN3343','joe''s comp',23214,1.0,400)
,(20190630,'IN3353','matt''s comp.',12222,3.0,6000)
,(20190630,'IN3353','matt''s comp.',32222,3.0,3000)

Select Date
      ,InvNunber
      ,Customer
      ,Item
      ,Qty  = sum(Qty)
      ,Sales = sum(Sales)
 From  @YourTable
 Group By 
   Grouping Sets (
                    (Date,InvNunber,Customer,Item)
                   ,(Date,InvNunber)
                   ,(left(Date,0))
                 )
  Order By left(Date,0) Desc
          ,Date
          ,InvNunber
          ,Customer Desc
```

**Returns**

```
Date    InvNunber   Customer        Item    Qty Sales
20190630    IN3343  joe's comp      23214   1   400
20190630    IN3343  joe's comp      23225   2   3000
20190630    IN3343  NULL            NULL    3   3400
20190630    IN3353  matt's comp.    12222   3   6000
20190630    IN3353  matt's comp.    32222   3   3000
20190630    IN3353  NULL            NULL    6   9000
NULL        NULL    NULL            NULL    9   12400
```

Comment: big thank you...grouping sets is what i need....is there a way to get the GRAND TOTAL as well, like you would with ROLLUP?

Comment: got it..love the simplicity