# How to limit the rollup combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have a query where i'm grouping by 4 different columns and I use a `ROLLUP` to create subtotals. The issue is that I get a subtotal for each groupings.

**Objective:**

How can I limit the number of rollups. I.e. I want to only have the subtotal for `device` and `game`.

**Current Query:**

```
select date,site,device,game,....
group by date,site,device,game
with rollup
```

Comment: Take peek at grouping sets Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827331/sql-query-how-to-create-subtotal-rows-when-there-is-no-aggregate-function/56827526#56827526

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grouping sets`:

```
select date, site, device, game, ....
from
group by grouping sets ( (date, site, device, game), (device), (game))
```