# SQL Grand Total row from Multi table Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been able to use the below SQL query to give me 4 rows of data

```
SELECT 'Sales Order ' as Type, Format(Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), 
'#.00') As NetAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount), '#.00') As 
MarginAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount)/Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), 
'#.00%') As Margin
From T_SalesOrder as T1
Where cast(T1.C_Date as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date) AND T1.C_OrderType 
!= 'BK' AND T1.C_OrderType != 'INV'

Union

SELECT 'Despatch Notes ' AS Type, Format(Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), 
'#.00') As NetAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount), '#.00') As 
MarginAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount)/Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), 
'#.00%') As Margin
From T_SalesDeliveryNote as T1
Where cast(T1.C_Date as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date) AND T1.C_Order is 
null AND T1.C_BillingStatus = '0'

Union

SELECT 'Invoices ' AS Type, Format(Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), '#.00') 
As NetAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount), '#.00') As MarginAmount, 
Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount)/Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), '#.00%') As 
Margin
From T_SalesInvoice as T1
Where cast(T1.C_Date as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date) And 
T1.C_DeliveryNote is null And T1.C_SourceOrder is null and T1.C_InvoiceType 
= '0'

Union

SELECT 'Credit Notes ' AS Type, Format(Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), '- 
#.00') As NetAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount), '-#.00') As 
MarginAmount, Format(Sum(T1.C_MarginAmount)/Sum(T1.C_NetAmountLessDiscount), 
'#.00%') As Margin
From T_SalesCreditNote as T1
Where cast(T1.C_Date as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)
```

This gives me a breakdown of the orders as I need but I also want to have a Grand Total row that sums each column.

If I  insert the above sql query into the below

```
Select 'Grand Total', Sum(CAST(NetAmount AS float)), Sum(CAST(MarginAmount 
AS float)),null
From
(
-----Above SQL Query in Here
)tbl
```

I get one single line with the correct totals but no breakdown rows.

How can I do this so it displays the four rows of each type and a grand total row at the bottom.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi JNevill, this is using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: May be you can add to a temporary table to hold the four rows and evaluate the four rows result to final row. You can then return the temporary table

Comment: Take a peek into GROUPING SETS... For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827331/sql-query-how-to-create-subtotal-rows-when-there-is-no-aggregate-function/56827526#56827526

Comment: Hi John, This has given me what I need thanks. Just need to be able to add a name in the type column (i.e Grand Total) but can`t seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE).

```
WITH t AS(
    -- Your query goes here
    -- SELECT 1 AS A, 'Sales Order' ...
    -- UNION SELECT 2 AS A, 'Despatch Notes' ...
    -- UNION SELECT 3 AS A, 'Invoices' ...
    -- UNION SELECT 4 AS A, 'Credit Notes' ...
)
SELECT
    A,
    Type,
    NetAmount,
    MarginAmount,
    Margin
FROM
    t
UNION SELECT
    5 AS A,
    'Grand Total' AS Type,
    FORMAT(SUM(CAST(NetAmount AS FLOAT)), '#.00') As NetAmount,
    FORMAT(SUM(CAST(MarginAmount AS FLOAT)), '#.00') As MarginAmount,
    NULL
FROM
    t
ORDER BY
    A
```

*Note: I added formatting the total values to ensure the total values of NetAmount and MarginAmount to share the same data type as the breakdown values. Consider to remove formatting the values from your query and add it to the presentation layer of your application.*

Comment: Hi Pilosa, This has almost given me exactly what I require but because this is sorted by type the Grand total row is in the middle. Do you know how to order this the same way as the selects are in my query.

Comment: You could add a column (see column A in my updated answer) to order the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping with a [ROLLUP](http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-rollup/) might be just the trick for this.

**Simplified Example Snippet:**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 NetAmount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 NetAmount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Name, NetAmount) 
VALUES ('A', 4.1), ('A', 6.1);

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Name, NetAmount) 
VALUES ('B', 9.1), ('B', 11.1);

WITH CTE_AMOUNTS AS
(
    SELECT 'T1' as [Type],
    SUM(NetAmount) AS [NetAmount]
    FROM @Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'T2', SUM(NetAmount)
    FROM @Table2
)
SELECT 
COALESCE([Type], 'Grand Total') AS [Type],
SUM([NetAmount]) AS [NetAmount]
FROM CTE_AMOUNTS
GROUP BY Type WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY GROUPING_ID(Type), Type;
```

**Returns:**

```
Type        NetAmount
T1          10,20
T2          20,20
Grand Total 30,40
```