# How to add subtotals (several subtotal rows) by customer in access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thanks in advance for your support.

I have an Access table with the following structure:

| Customer | Ticket | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | A | 100 |
| John | C | 200 |
| John | F | 100 |
| Max | B | 200 |
| Max | D | 50 |
| Max | E | 80 |

What I am trying to achieve is to add totals rows by customer to the table so that the totals rows and the individual transactions of all customers are visible at the same table. Something like this:

| Customer | Ticket | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TOTAL John |  | 400 |
| John | A | 100 |
| John | C | 200 |
| John | F | 100 |
| TOTAL Max |  | 330 |
| Max | B | 200 |
| Max | D | 50 |
| Max | E | 80 |

The amount of tickets varies from one customer to another and each customer's name is unique. Is there a Query and/or Access command to do this?

Thanks again.

Comment: Would have to build an aggregate query then a UNION query to combine with table. Instead, build a report using Sorting & Grouping feature with aggregate calcs in textboxes.

Comment: Or convert to another db like SQLServer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827331/sql-query-how-to-create-subtotal-rows-when-there-is-no-aggregate-function

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/907b646b-a2d3-4005-9964-b3fdbade7930/rollup-in-access-to-calculate-subtotals

Comment: Thanks a lot June, the UNION query worked just fine. Cheers!